# problems for parse complicate json post data in django

Tags: django, urllib2, simplejson

I have a django parse function as:

```
def parse_org(request):
    try:
       org = simplejson.loads(request.POST['org'])
    except Exception:
       traceback.print_exc()
    print org
```

I got the decode error.

On the client side, the script version(code are pasted in later part) works fine, but recently I want to write a python version to do load test, so I write the following code in a python client script to send request:

```
data_dict = {}
org = ["UCSD", "MIT"]
data_dict["org"] = org
req = urllib2.Request(request_url, urllib.urlencode(data_dict), headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout = 5)
```

Then the parse code at the django site gets parsing error. I compare the correct javascript version and the wrong python clients, the only difference is the single and double quote, 
the wrong parsed input at django side is:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'org': [u"['UCSD', 'MIT']"], ....
```

the correct input is:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'org': [u'["UCSD","MIT"]'], ....
```

For your reference, the javascript side looks like(the django can correctly parse the org as array):

```
var org = [];
org.push("UCSD")
org.push("MIT")
var data = {"org":  JSON.stringify(org), ...
           }
$.post(url, data, function(data){
    callback(data);
});
```

I searched a lot, but still can't find why the python client can't work but the javascript client can work. Is it related with the urllib's urlencode? and why there is single and double quote difference there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are posting it using jquery's post method, you can directly acces it via request.POST. why do u want to parse it with simplejson.loads. Thats unncessary.3

Comment: Thanks, but I print request.POST['org'], it's a unicode string. Also I didn't use jquery post method, that jquery is the javascript client, it's correct. I met problem when using python's urlopen request.

Comment: if you want it to be an ascii string give str(request.POST['xxx'])